# How to search whole redis database for string?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I need to debug a session problem, so I have to search for a certain string in the whole redis database. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you check https://redisearch.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug it by using `redis-cli monitor | tee monitor_log.txt` and then searching in the file.